# How to sort string date angularjs

Tags: angularjs, date

How sort string date format 24.01.2017 ( descending )
I tried with `Date.parse('24.01.2017');` -> but incorrect format

How sort date like this? 
in controller or view 
Thanks

Getting data from api
want sort by `_title`
[image]

Comment: add your html and javascript

Comment: Where a you while converting the date ? in a controller ? in the view ? You can usually sort dates in a ng-repeat with an orderby filter

Comment: with `orderBy : _title `
it sorting by first digit means 05.11.12 and 06.12.11 first will be  with 05

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `orderBy` filter with a custom comparing function:

JS:

```
$scope.entries = [
  {date: '05.02.2001'},
  {date: '01.20.1930'},
  {date: '03.20.2020'} 
]

$scope.compareDates = function(date1, date2) {
  console.log(date1)
  var split1 = date1.value.split('.');
  var split2 = date2.value.split('.');

  var date1compare = split1[2] + split1[1] + split1[0];
  var date2compare = split2[2] + split2[1] + split2[0];

  return (date1compare > date2compare ? 1 : -1)
}
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="entry in entries | orderBy:'date':false:compareDates">
    {{entry.date}}
</div>
```

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/LETAFDoD5fub63tKI5Ne?p=preview