# Get latest 3 dates in ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs

I have the table below, I want to display only the latest 3 dates in `ng-repeat`. I used `orderBy` with `-` and limited the results to 3.

```
╔════╦═════════════════╦══════════╗
║ id ║      name       ║   date   ║
╠════╬═════════════════╬══════════╣
║  0 ║ Live Cooking    ║ 08/10/17 ║
║  1 ║ Rainy Season    ║ 08/29/17 ║
║  2 ║ Heart-Healthy   ║ 09/25/17 ║
║  3 ║ 5th Anniversary ║ 09/26/17 ║
║  4 ║ Health Living   ║ 02/15/18 ║
║  5 ║ Indoor Party    ║ 02/20/18 ║
╚════╩═════════════════╩══════════╝
```

**html**

```
<div class="recent-article_container">
    <h3>Recent Articles</h3>
    <a href="{{art.page}}" class="nav_refresh" ng-repeat="art in mainCtrl.articles | orderBy:'-date' | limitTo:3">
        <div class="recent-article">
            <div class="media-body">
                <h5 class="recent-article_title">{{art.name}}</h5>
                <small class="article_date pull-left">{{art.date}}</small>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

**controller**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
app.controller('MainController', function ($scope, $http) {
    var self = this;
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '../json/article-archives.json',
        data: self.articles
    }).then(function (response) {
        self.articles = response.data;
    }, function () { console.log('Error'); });
});
```

I want to get the results below:

```
╔════╦═════════════════╦══════════╗
║ id ║      name       ║   date   ║
╠════╬═════════════════╬══════════╣
║  5 ║ Indoor Party    ║ 02/20/18 ║
║  4 ║ Health Living   ║ 02/15/18 ║
║  3 ║ 5th Anniversary ║ 09/26/17 ║
╚════╩═════════════════╩══════════╝
```

but it's not working as expected, I also tried it using `-id` but it doesn't work too. How do I get the results with the latest 3 dates in descending order?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort string date angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41487092/2435473)

Comment: Try this ng-repeat = "art in mainCtrl.articles  | limitTo: -3"

Comment: what's your response? it seems your date is in String format

Comment: @MohamedSameer I don't know why but it worked but it's not in desc order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use limitTo to get last three results and orderBy for your orders.

```
  <a href="{{art.page}}" class="nav_refresh" ng-repeat="art in mainCtrl.articles | limitTo:-3 | orderBy:'-id'">
```

Hope it will solved your problem

Answer (score 1):

**First:**
You have to add custom compare function in controller as your date is not formatted for orderby. The method `$scope.compareDates` has been added in the code.

**Second:**
You need to add the custom function in your html as follows and I think you already have a code like `<div ng-controller = "MainController">` before the following line:

```
 <a href="{{art.page}}" class="nav_refresh" ng-repeat="art in articles | orderBy:'date':true:compareDates | limitTo:3">
```

**Third:**
To access controller scope variable, you need to add `$scope.` before variable name. I have changed:

```
$scope.articles = {};
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '../json/article-archives.json',
    data: $scope.articles
}).then(function (response) {
    $scope.articles = response.data;
},
```

> **Final Solution:**

Updated solution for the problem given here, just open your HTTP post code:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
app.controller('MainController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.articles = [
                       {
                           date:'6/11/2018',
                           name: 'Test1'
        
                       },
                       {
                           date:'6/11/2017',
                           name: 'Test2'
        
                       },
                       {
                           date:'6/11/2019',
                           name: 'Test3'
        
                       }
                       ,
                       {
                           date:'6/11/2007',
                           name: 'Test3'
        
                       }
                      
             ];
    //$http({
    //    method: 'POST',
    //    url: './article.json',
     //   data: $scope.articles
    //}).then(function (response) {
    //    $scope.articles = response.data;
    //}, function () { console.log('Error'); });

   $scope.compareDates = function(date1, date2) {
    console.log(date1)
    var split1 = (date1 + '').split('/');
    var split2 = (date2 + '').split('/');

    var date1compare = split1[2] + split1[0] + split1[1];
    var date2compare = split2[2] + split2[0] + split2[1];

    return (date1compare > date2compare ? -1 : 1);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app = "myApp">
<div ng-controller = "MainController">
  <div class="recent-article_container">
      <h3>Recent Articles</h3>
      <a href="{{art.page}}" class="nav_refresh" ng-repeat="art in articles | orderBy:'date':true:compareDates | limitTo:3">
          <div class="recent-article">
              <div class="media-body">
                  <h5 class="recent-article_title">{{art.name}}</h5>
                  <small class="article_date pull-left">{{art.date}}</small>
              </div>
          </div>
      </a>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm still not getting the right dates but I'll look into the right date format for ng-repeat. Thanks.

Comment: I changed $scope.compareDates to  self.compareDates but I still can't get the right result.

Comment: No. Don't change to self. Add $scope to all that will be used from html.

Comment: I have this code `var self = this;` so if I don't change it to `self.` I will get errors.

Comment: Did your code have the line: <div ng-controller = "MainController as mainCtrl">

Comment: I'll upvote your answer since you have a working snippet but I won't mark it as answer since I prefer the code provided by Mohamed Sameer which is shorter with the `orderBy:'-id'`. Please understand. Thank you.